# Bootstrap Split Progress Bars

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, breadcrumbs

I can't for the life of me figure out the best way to do this. I've tried using progress bars, using individual divs, nothing seems to work. I found examples on the web attempting to do this but to no avail.

Here's what i'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Here's what I have:

[image]

I seem to be headed in the right direction but can't figure it out. I'd like to accomplish this strictly with CSS if possible. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```css
#breadcrumbs-two{
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
}

#breadcrumbs-two li{
  float: left;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 1em;
}

#breadcrumbs-two a{
  background: #ddd;
  padding: .7em 1em;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  position: relative;
}

#breadcrumbs-two a:hover{
  background: #99db76;
}

#breadcrumbs-two a::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  border-width: 1.5em 0 1.5em 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ddd #ddd #ddd transparent;
  left: -1em;
}

#breadcrumbs-two a:hover::before{
  border-color: #99db76 #99db76 #99db76 transparent;
}

#breadcrumbs-two a::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  border-top: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-left: 1em solid #ddd;
  right: -1em;
}

#breadcrumbs-two a:hover::after{
  border-left-color: #99db76;
}

#breadcrumbs-two .current,
#breadcrumbs-two .current:hover{
  font-weight: bold;
  background: none;
}

#breadcrumbs-two .current::after,
#breadcrumbs-two .current::before{
  content: normal;
}
```

```html
<ul id="breadcrumbs-two">
                <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Vivamus nisi eros</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Nulla sed lorem risus</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="current">Current crumb</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Show your code with attempts please.

Comment: @flppv I added the snippet to the original post. This is an example i was able to pull from a tutorial. While its in the general direction I'd like to go - it's not what's pictured in what I am looking for. I don't expect you to 'recreate' it, though some direction would be awesome. I couldn't get the spacing between the different options to be a diagonal line or the :first-child:before border radius like the one pictured.

Comment: You want to achieve using prograss bar or breadcrumb?

Comment: @sharvan Either of the two methods would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have achieved with using bootstrap breadcrumb. I hope this will be helpful. If you need any further assistance reply with comment.

```css
nav .breadcrumb {
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
}

.breadcrumb .breadcrumb-item a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 18px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #999 !important;
    z-index: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.breadcrumb .breadcrumb-item {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    background: #575763;
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 16px;
}

.breadcrumb-item:before {
    content: "" !important;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    border-top: 16px solid #575763;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    left: -10px;
    top: 0;
    height: 16px;
}

.breadcrumb-item:after {
    content: "" !important;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    border-top: 16px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid #575763;
    right: -10px;
    top: 0;
    height: 16px;
}

.breadcrumb .breadcrumb-item:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}

.breadcrumb .breadcrumb-item:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
}

.breadcrumb .breadcrumb-item:last-child:after {
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
}

.breadcrumb .breadcrumb-item.active:first-child:before {
    border-top: 16px solid transparent;
}

.breadcrumb .breadcrumb-item.active {
    background: #61c988;
}

.breadcrumb-item.active:before {
    border-top: 16px solid #61c988;
}

.breadcrumb-item.active:after {
    border-left: 10px solid #61c988;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb my-2">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active"><a href="#">New</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active"><a href="#">In-Review</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a>Interview</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a>Offered</a></li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```css
ul.breadcrumbs>li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  background: #61C988;
  padding: 3px 8px 3px 8px;
}

ul.breadcrumbs>li:nth-child(1) {
  border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
}

ul.breadcrumbs>li:last-child {
  border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
}

ul.breadcrumbs>li.current {
  background: #575763;
}

ul.breadcrumbs>li>a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}

ul.breadcrumbs>li.current>a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
  <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Vivamus nisi eros</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Nulla sed lorem risus</a></li>
  <li class="current"><a href="">Current crumb</a></li>
</ul>
```